# website framework w/o mysql

Tags: php, content-management-system, menu

I'm looking for some tool or framework to build a simple website with a menu structure and some content (max 100 pages).

Usually I would try something like Drupal or Joomla, but here they would be overkill, and I don't want to install a database on the target system. Instead I'd like to configure that small site by using xml (or similar flat file). Content should be stored in separate flat files (html, php).

Interpreted languages like php or perl are preferred. Is there something like that out there?

Comment: i don't think i would build a one page website with out a db theses days.

Comment: @Dagon - he didn't say without database and he aims for max 100 pages. he just needs noSQL file based like coachDB or one file database like sqlLite.

Comment: "Content should be stored in separate flat files" sounds like no db to me

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly for websites, but [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) is a flat-file wiki-system with templating and user-level access. No DB required. Easy to customize

Note: ... and store the content in flat-files, in a tree-like structure.

Answer (score 1):

Another wiki option to use is [pmwiki](http://www.pmwiki.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CushyCMS could do the trick for you.
http://www.cushycms.com/

Comment: Yep it's hosted, I don't see why it doesn't fit into the post, if that's the point of your comment. Actually if you are not using a DB by yourself, I think it's a good choice to consider.